# Tensorflow export frozen graph with multiple ckpt.data files

Tags: tensorflow

I've finished training an object detection network, starting from the pre-trained ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco model and retraining to detect 10 of my own classes. I first trained my model on my laptop and all worked as planned but the training was too slow to be effective. I restarted training on google cloud service, and now the output files are

```
model.ckpt-*.data-00000-of-00003
model.ckpt-*.data-00001-of-00003
model.ckpt-*.data-00002-of-00003
model.ckpt-*.index
model.ckpt-*.meta
```

(rather than a single model.ckpt-*.data-00000-of-00001 file)

I ran the export_inference_graph.py script as normal on this set of files and got a frozen_inference_graph.pb file, but when I attempt to plug it into the rest of my code as I can with the pre-trained model, I get this error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception:OpenCV(4.0.1) 
/tmp/opencv-20190105-31032-o160to/opencv-4.0.1/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:530: 
error: (-2:Unspecified error) Const input blob for weights not found in function 'getConstBlob'
```

I believe this is because all three .data files are not being incorporated fully/correctly when exporting the model. I'm wondering how to either export a frozen graph using all three files or how to compress/combine the three files into a single .data file?

UPDATE: contents of export_inference_graph.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from google.protobuf import text_format
from object_detection import exporter
from object_detection.protos import pipeline_pb2

slim = tf.contrib.slim
flags = tf.app.flags

flags.DEFINE_string('input_type', 'image_tensor', 'Type of input node. Can be '
                    'one of [`image_tensor`, `encoded_image_string_tensor`, '
                    '`tf_example`]')
flags.DEFINE_string('input_shape', None,
                    'If input_type is `image_tensor`, this can explicitly set '
                    'the shape of this input tensor to a fixed size. The '
                    'dimensions are to be provided as a comma-separated list '
                    'of integers. A value of -1 can be used for unknown '
                    'dimensions. If not specified, for an `image_tensor, the '
                    'default shape will be partially specified as '
                    '`[None, None, None, 3]`.')
flags.DEFINE_string('pipeline_config_path', None,
                    'Path to a pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig config '
                    'file.')
flags.DEFINE_string('trained_checkpoint_prefix', None,
                    'Path to trained checkpoint, typically of the form '
                    'path/to/model.ckpt')
flags.DEFINE_string('output_directory', None, 'Path to write outputs.')
flags.DEFINE_string('config_override', '',
                    'pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig '
                    'text proto to override pipeline_config_path.')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('write_inference_graph', False,
                     'If true, writes inference graph to disk.')
tf.app.flags.mark_flag_as_required('pipeline_config_path')
tf.app.flags.mark_flag_as_required('trained_checkpoint_prefix')
tf.app.flags.mark_flag_as_required('output_directory')
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS

def main(_):
  pipeline_config = pipeline_pb2.TrainEvalPipelineConfig()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(FLAGS.pipeline_config_path, 'r') as f:
    text_format.Merge(f.read(), pipeline_config)
  text_format.Merge(FLAGS.config_override, pipeline_config)
  if FLAGS.input_shape:
    input_shape = [
        int(dim) if dim != '-1' else None
        for dim in FLAGS.input_shape.split(',')
    ]
  else:
    input_shape = None
  exporter.export_inference_graph(
      FLAGS.input_type, pipeline_config, FLAGS.trained_checkpoint_prefix,
      FLAGS.output_directory, input_shape=input_shape,
      write_inference_graph=FLAGS.write_inference_graph)


if __name__ == '__main__':

  tf.app.run()
```

Command to run this script with flags:

```
python scripts/export_inference_graph.py \
    --input_type image_tensor \
    --pipeline_config_path training/ssd_mobilenet_v3_coco.config \
    --checkpoint_path gsc/model.ckpt-${CHECKPOINT_NUMBER} \
    --inference_graph_path gsc/output_inference_graph.pb
```

Comment: Can we see export_inference_graph.py ?

Comment: @DecentGradient Just added it!

Comment: Can you try running it with the checkpoint path just being the directory and not pointing to a specific model.ckpt file

Comment: @DecentGradient changing --checkpoint_path to just the gsc directory gives `absl.flags._exceptions.IllegalFlagValueError: flag --trained_checkpoint_prefix=None: Flag --trained_checkpoint_prefix must have a value other than None`

Comment: Thanks, can you try running with  --trained_checkpoint_prefix gsc/models.ckpt

Comment: @DecentGradient That returned the error: `ValueError: The passed save_path is not a valid checkpoint: gsc/models.ckpt`

Comment: Hmm, in your question the checkpoint files had a -* is that intentional

Comment: @DecentGradient, yes, that just refers to the training checkpoint number so my specific checkpoint was 293760 which was inserted there